# binary subtraction with a simple neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to create a simple ANN that takes inputs `x1` and `x2`, counts the number of ones (ON) in each input and returns `x1 - x2`. The network appears to train correctly when I use a single example. However, when I start to add other examples, the results are terrible. I've tried adjusting the regularisation strength, no. iterations, and learning rate, but it didn't appear to help. My understanding is that the optimal number of hidden layer neurons is `len(x1) + len(x2)`, which is what I've implemented. Any help would be great.

```
import os
import fnmatch
import numpy as np

class Neuron:
    def __init__(self,n):
        #create weights (+1 is for bias)
        self.weights = np.random.randn(n+1) / np.sqrt(n)
        self.lr = 1e-2
        self.reg = 0.01

    def linear(self,x):
        #apply linear step
        x = np.append(x,1)
        return np.dot(self.weights,x)

    def output(self,x):
        #apply sigmoid step
        preact = self.linear(x)
        self.out =  1/(1+np.exp(-preact))
        return self.out

    def apply_gradients(self):
        #update weights
        self.weights -= self.gradients * self.lr

    def calculate_gradients(self,loss):
        #calculate gradients
        self.gradients = loss * self.out * (1-self.out)
        return self.gradients

    def _reg(self):
        return (self.reg*np.sum((self.weights)))

def main(argv=None):

    num_epochs = 1000

    #inputs
    x1 = [[1,1,1],[1,1,0]]
    x2 = [[1,1,0],[1,1,0]]
    x = np.append(x1,x2,axis=1)

    #labels: binary substraction x1-x2
    y = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,0,0]])

    _,n = y.shape
    hln = 2*n

    hidden_out = np.array(np.zeros(hln))
    y_ = np.array(np.zeros(n))
    reg_value = np.array(np.zeros(n))
    loss = np.array(np.zeros(n))

    #initialise the hidden layer neurons
    hidden_layer = []
    for i in range(hln):
        hidden_layer.append(Neuron(2*n))

    #initialise the output layer neurons
    out_layer = []
    for i in range(n):
        out_layer.append(Neuron(hln))

    rows,cols = x.shape

    #run through the epochs
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        #run through the samples
        for data in range(rows):

            #pass the data through the hidden layer
            for i in range(len(hidden_layer)):
                hidden_out[i]=hidden_layer[i].output(x[data,:])

            #pass the hidden layer output through the output layer
            for i in range(len(out_layer)):
                y_[i] = out_layer[i].output(hidden_out)
                #get the reg value
                reg_value[i] = out_layer[i]._reg()

            #calculate L1 loss
            loss = y_ - y[data,:] + reg_value

            #calculate gradients of output layer
            for i in range(len(out_layer)):
                out_layer[i].calculate_gradients(loss[i])

            #calculate gradients of hidden layer
            for i in range(len(hidden_layer)):
                back_vec = 0
                for j in range(len(out_layer)):
                    #sum all the output weights coming back into a hidden neuron
                    back_vec += out_layer[j].weights[i]*loss[j]
                #send the backwards value through the hidden neuron
                hidden_layer[i].calculate_gradients(back_vec)

            #apply gradient to output layer
            for i in range(len(out_layer)):
                out_layer[i].apply_gradients()

            #apply gradients to hidden layer
            for i in range(len(hidden_layer)):
                hidden_layer[i].apply_gradients()

            #output the final results
            if epoch == num_epochs-1:
                print((y_))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a training set in order to train a ML model (a neural network, in this case). Generalize a somewhat complex operation (binary difference) from just two training examples is not an easy task.

My suggestion would be to create a full training set before starting building the network; since you are working with fixed-length (3) binary arrays, you can easily create all the possibilities (8 * 8 = 64 training samples), leave a small percent out for validation and train with the rest.

Comment: With two examples in my training set as above, shouldn't it just be over-fitting for those two examples? I'm planning on building the dataset, but I want to make sure it trains properly first.

Comment: That's weird. Then what do you mean by "the results are terrible"? What exactly changes in the prediction when you switch from training with just one sample to two samples?

Comment: If I remove the second example and just have: 
`x1 = [[1,1,1]]` 
`x2 = [[1,1,0]]` 
I get:
 `[ 0.14820886  0.18161722  0.85750508]`

If I include the second example:
    `x1 = [[1,1,1],[1,1,0]]`
   ` x2 = [[1,1,0],[1,1,0]]`

I get: 
`[ 0.07758648  0.08428804  0.50992065]
[ 0.08043145  0.08178883  0.49312955]`

I tried it with 3 examples at one point and it also went weird...